# Why does AutoGenerateBindingRedirects produce a config file with multiple assemblyBinding elements?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

We've recently moved to having our binding redirects automatically generated, and in general its been great. We have just noticed something interesting though and I couldn't find an answer to why, so I was hoping SO might help.

We've noticed then the generated .exe.config has multiple `<assemblyBinding>` elements each detailing one `<dependentAssembly>` entry. Even though `assemblyBinding` elements can contain many `dependentAssembly` elements. Have one `<assemblyBinding>` element is even how the microsoft docs are shown

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#specify-assembly-binding-in-configuration-files

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />
        <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app,
          publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="mySecondAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="myThirdAssembly"
        publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
        culture="en-us" />
        <!-- Publisher policy can be set only in the app
          configuration file. -->
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

However with automatic binding redirects enabled our output looks more like this

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />
        <!-- Assembly versions can be redirected in app,
          publisher policy, or machine configuration files. -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="mySecondAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
          culture="en-us" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="myThirdAssembly"
        publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
        culture="en-us" />
        <!-- Publisher policy can be set only in the app
          configuration file. -->
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

PS. You are maybe wondering why I even care. The reason is, some part of our testing process involves inspect the exe.config and extracting info from it (and sometimes updating the binding redirect) and it suddenly stopped working due to this. We can fix that, but it got me curious

Comment: Hi @Dave, imho that question is better preserved at the [corresponding github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) for it is indeed very deep down the rabbit hole.

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this in the future, this is the 'issue' I raised in the github repo
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/31157